# How to I extract a set of digits using regular expressions

Tags: .net, regex

I need to extract the 8 or 10 digits after the last backslash. I don't use regular expressions enough, but this is what I have so far `(?!\\\\)(?<=.*\\)(?:[^\d]*)(?<id>\d+)(?:[^\d])`

```
\\server\root\list\listName 082713\type_102113\25765199.bpo.pdf
\\server\root\list\listName 082713\type_102113\25765280.bpo.pdf
\\server\root\list\listName 082713\type_102113\25779752.bpo.pdf
\\server\root\list\listName 082713\type_102113\NAME1 0020412714_BPO.pdf
\\server\root\list\listName 082713\type_102113\NAME2 0020421822_BPO.pdf
\\server\root\list\listName 082713\type_102113\NAME3 0020443370_BPO.pdf

a:\listName 082713\type_102113\25765199.bpo.pdf
a:\listName 082713\type_102113\25765280.bpo.pdf
a:\listName 082713\type_102113\25779752.bpo.pdf
a:\listName 082713\type_102113\NAME1 0020412714_BPO.pdf
a:\listName 082713\type_102113\NAME2 0020421822_BPO.pdf
a:\listName 082713\type_102113\NAME3 0020443370_BPO.pdf
```

#### More Generic

With the help of 'hwnd', the following expression actually solves this question, but helps with my goal of extracting a set of digits in folder names also, but easily changing the "lookaround" expressions.

```
(?<![^\\\D ])(?<id>\d+(?:-\d+)?)(?=(?:(?:\.[a-z]|[_-])))
```

Comment: Why not split the string first and then use a simpler regex on the last part?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your over thinking this expression it seems. I would go with a **Negative Lookbehind** here.

```
(?<![^\\ ])\d{8,10}
```

Regular expression:

```
(?<!           look behind to see if there is not:
 [^\\ ]        any character except: '\\', ' '
)              end of look-behind
\d{8,10}       digits (0-9) (between 8 and 10 times)
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/iS1yX2)

Another solution with you having either a *dot* or *underscore* following the last set of numbers after the last backslash, would be a **Positive Lookahead**.

```
(\d+)(?=[._])
```

See [live demo](http://regex101.com/r/dL8uY3)

Comment: >>Your over thinking this expression it seems<< Yes, but I am also trying to find the one expression that handles other formats, such as the digits in the directory path.

Comment: Hope it helped you out :)

Answer (score 1):

A pattern like this should work in multiline mode:

```
(?<id>\d+)[^\\\d]*$
```

This will match one or more digits, captured in group `"id"`, followed by zero or more of any character other than a backslash or digit, followed by the end of the line.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe I'm missing something, but I would go with following:

```
([0-9]{10}|[0-9]{8})[^\\]+$
```

You can check it working on [**DEMO**](http://regexr.com?36s0k).